# Append data to data.table from a function that is looped in R

Tags: r, function, csv, for-loop

I've created a function with a data.table:

```
testfunction <- function(EvalDate) {
    EvalDate <- as.Date(EvalDate,"%Y-%m-%d")
    CurrData <- DT[DT$ActivityDate <= EvalDate, ] 
}

tmpseq <- seq(as.Date("2013-02-01"),length=12,by="months")-1

for (i in 1:length(tmpseq)) 
 {
  testfunction(tmpseq[i])
 }
```

Essentially the function creates a data.frame with for every month in the iteration.
I initially wrote out each iteration into a .csv file in the function:

```
filename <- paste("CurrData_", as.character(EvalDate,format="%y%m%d"), ".csv", sep="") 
write.table(CurrData, file = filename ,row.names=FALSE, na="",col.names=TRUE, sep=",")
```

But I am looking to append all iterations from the loop into 1 data frame before writing it out to .csv

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try:

```
lst <- list()
for(i in 1:length(tmpseq)){
  lst[[i]] <- testfunction(tmpseq[i])
}
Reduce(rbind, lst)
```